# How to fail fast(er) when trying to update a package in Haskell?

Tags: haskell, cabal, haskell-stack

### Problem

In a very used library
[haddock](https://github.com/haskell/haddock/blob/4cf2f4d8f6bd5588c2659e343573c5d30b329d37/haddock-api/src/Haddock/InterfaceFile.hs#L97) we have

```
#if MIN_VERSION_ghc(9,2,0) && !MIN_VERSION_ghc(9,3,0)
```

Those hidden dependencies make it into the *built* binary.

So, say, [haddocset](https://github.com/philopon/haddocset) builds just fine thanks to [stack.yaml](https://github.com/philopon/haddocset/blob/master/stack.yaml) targeting `lts-12.0`, with extra-dependency

```yaml
extra-deps:
- haddock-api-2.20.0
- haddock-library-1.6.0
```

And then when running the actual executable

```
haddock: internal error: /Users/nicolas/.stack/programs/x86_64-osx/ghc-8.4.4/lib/ghc-8.4.4/settings: openFile: does not exist (No such file or directory)
```

### Updating with Stackage

To update  [haddocset](https://github.com/philopon/haddocset) to `lts-18.25` as far as I understand I have to update the "extra-deps" which entails to

- check GHC version (in my case from LTS-18.25 so ghc 8.10.7).
- check which version of the `base` library 8.10.7 comes with in the [release notes](https://downloads.haskell.org/%7Eghc/8.10.7/docs/html/users_guide/8.10.7-notes.html) so `4.14.3.0`
- browse through [hackage](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/haddock-api) to find which version of that package has a compatible `base` library so its [haddock-api-2.24.0](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/haddock-api-2.24.0)
- same for finding  `hsdev-0.3.1.4` `hdocs-0.4.4.1`
- then `stack build` suggests to add

```
- MonadCatchIO-transformers-0.3.1.3@sha256:468a6f12fd3821d2ab6301cc3543930c05e5117118917c6857ea383bdcc96c54,1127
- ghc-syb-utils-0.2.3.3@sha256:fc4cd944bbd4d5160b2ee8bb458974a135c0abbd9941fb6e5f9180164efd091a,1302
```

which look compatible on hackage.

Then I get an error from `ghc-syb-utils`

```hs
ghc-syb-utils       > /private/var/folders/nw/tfpqw8w97hq8kw7kvf1qst2w0000gn/T/stack-03a7d85958fa8f57/ghc-syb-utils-0.2.3.3/GHC/SYB/Utils.hs:258:64: error:
ghc-syb-utils       >     • Could not deduce (Outputable (HsOverLit RdrName))
```

which says something on [ghc-syb-utils](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/ghc-syb-utils) (`ghc (>=7.10 && <8.6)`) and something else on [github](https://github.com/DanielG/ghc-syb) ("GHC 8.0 or later is not supported")

So I can't build this binary for `8.10.7`/`LTS-18.25`.

### Updating with Cabal

I am no expert at all on cabal, because having random build plan depending on what is currently published is both **totally mad** for end-users, and a great freedom for library authors who want their updates to be picked up everywhere silently. And I am just a user here, wanting to install a binary.

Of course the project [haddocset](https://github.com/philopon/haddocset) as it is does **not** build with `cabal` anymore, although nothing has changed, because (I think) of the said madness, either with `v1-build` or `v2-build` prayer. Maybe some way do exist. I just don't know.

If in the [cabal file](https://github.com/philopon/haddocset/blob/master/haddocset.cabal) one set the bounds for `base` and `ghc`, relax the upper bounds for the other dependencies,  or else, there are only the usual message about "backjumping" from those invocation

```
[ 04:42:14 ] [ 1] ❯ cabal-3.4.1.0 v1-build
Resolving dependencies...
Warning: solver failed to find a solution:
Could not resolve dependencies:
[__0] trying: haddocset-0.4.3 (user goal)
[__1] next goal: base (dependency of haddocset)
[__1] rejecting: base-4.12.0.0/installed-4.12.0.0 (conflict: haddocset =>
base>=4.14.3.0 && <5)
[__1] fail (backjumping, conflict set: base, haddocset)
After searching the rest of the dependency tree exhaustively, these were the
goals I've had most trouble fulfilling: haddocset, base
Trying configure anyway.
Configuring haddocset-0.4.3...
cabal-3.4.1.0: Encountered missing or private dependencies:
base >=4.14.3.0 && <5,
conduit,
conduit-extra,
haddock-api >=2.15,
hsdev,
http-types,
resourcet,
sqlite-simple
```

```
[ 04:42:11 ] [ 130] ❯ cabal-3.4.1.0 v2-build
Resolving dependencies...
cabal-3.4.1.0: Could not resolve dependencies:
[__0] trying: haddocset-0.4.3 (user goal)
[__1] next goal: base (dependency of haddocset)
[__1] rejecting: base-4.12.0.0/installed-4.12.0.0 (conflict: haddocset =>
base>=4.14.3.0 && <5)
[__1] rejecting: base-4.16.0.0, base-4.15.1.0, base-4.15.0.0, base-4.14.3.0,
base-4.14.2.0, base-4.14.1.0, base-4.14.0.0, base-4.13.0.0, base-4.12.0.0,
base-4.11.1.0, base-4.11.0.0, base-4.10.1.0, base-4.10.0.0, base-4.9.1.0,
base-4.9.0.0, base-4.8.2.0, base-4.8.1.0, base-4.8.0.0, base-4.7.0.2,
base-4.7.0.1, base-4.7.0.0, base-4.6.0.1, base-4.6.0.0, base-4.5.1.0,
base-4.5.0.0, base-4.4.1.0, base-4.4.0.0, base-4.3.1.0, base-4.3.0.0,
base-4.2.0.2, base-4.2.0.1, base-4.2.0.0, base-4.1.0.0, base-4.0.0.0,
base-3.0.3.2, base-3.0.3.1 (constraint from non-upgradeable package requires
installed instance)
[__1] fail (backjumping, conflict set: base, haddocset)
After searching the rest of the dependency tree exhaustively, these were the
goals I've had most trouble fulfilling: base, haddocset
```

### Question

What are the **fastest** way, either with stack or with cabal, to spot that there are *real* code issue in `ghc-syb-utils`, so that it's not just a matter of updating dependencies ?

Comment: Those cabal v2-install errors about conflicting base versions indicate that you are using a GHC version that is too old. It says base 4.12 is installed, so you must be using GHC 8.6, which is not supported by haddocset.

Comment: isn't it cabal's job to use the correct version of GHC for that project ? stack builds it by executing the build plan (which includes having GHC 8.4.4). I guess I don't know what cabal does and how it does it, just that it has "dynamic" build plan which as far as I can tell are bound to fail *by design*

Comment: No, cabal doesn't manage external executables like GHC. It only manages Haskell packages. External executables can be managed with ghcup.

Comment: And yes, I used that to install ghc. I thought it was just for system install. so that's actually a global variable for cabal project then (!!!). I had 8.6.5, switched to 8.10.7, same result. the problem is that it's too new and cabal can't find a solution. As I unsertand it, I'd have to restore hackage as it was 4 years ago to imagine cabal might begin to work.

Comment: I can't imagine you'd get exactly the same error with v2-build and the GHC 8.10.7, because then at least the base version should match. Can you update your question with the new error message? I also don't know why you would have to restore hackage to an old state, cabal is perfectly capable of finding old versions of packages to use.

Comment: instead of "__1] rejecting: base-4.12.0.0/installed-4.12.0.0" I get "rejecting: base-4.14.3.0/installed-4.14.3.0". pristine haddocset as it is requires "(conflict: haddocset =>
base>=4.6 && <4.12)" which in both case is the reason why it fails with cabal. and based on what I understand cabal worked there is no hope to build that lib with  it, unless there are some new "history" feature to build the plan as hackage was back in the days when haddocset was once built, or with some other new feature I am unaware of

Comment: Okay, that means you are compiling a different version of haddocset than you do in the main post, because there is says: `(conflict: haddocset => base>=4.14.3.0 && <5)`. This other version of haddocset requires an older version of GHC, GHC 8.4 is the latest that will work with base 4.11.

Comment: I would have *wanted* cabal to find a build plan, so I ask it to use `base>=4.14.3.0 && <5)`. I thought that's how cabal worked : it figures out a build plan based on the constraints (which is never the same as hackage moves on...)

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/242194/discussion-between-noughtmare-and-nicolas).